# How to remove a particular digit from an integer using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers, digits

I have an integer containing various digits, I want to remove `4th` digit from an integer. How can I achieve that ?

Example **:**

```
let number = 789012345
```

Here I want to remove `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **:**

```js
// Input
let number = 789012345;

// Convert number into a string
let numberStr = number.toString();

// Replace the 0 with empty string
const res = numberStr.replace(numberStr[3], '');

// Convert string into a number.
console.log(Number(res));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this procedure:

- Decide if you want to remove digits by index or by value, the following demo will remove by value, which means it will remove all values that match
- Convert the number into a string
- Convert the string to an array with `Array.from`
- Use `Array#filter` to remove target digit(s)
- Use `Array#join` to create a string
- Use `+` to convert to string back into a numeric value

```js
const n = 789012345;
const m = +Array.from( n.toString() ).filter(num => +num !== 0).join("");
console.log( m );
```

Answer (score 0):

[Rohìt Jíndal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71769675/6036546) is excellent. I just want to point out another way you could do this with [`string.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and capturing groups.

```js
function removeDigit(input, index) {
  let exp = new RegExp(`^(\\d{${index}})(\\d)(.+)$`);
  return parseInt(input.toString().replace(exp, '$1$3'));
}

let output = removeDigit(789012345, 3);
console.log(output); // 78912345
```

In this example, I have created a new [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object from a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in order to inject the `index`.

The first capturing group contains all digits up to the desired index. The second contains the digit we want to remove and the third contains the remainder of the string.

We then return an integer parsed from the string combination of only the first and third capturing groups.

Answer (score 0):

```
let number = 789012345;
let array_number = [...number.toString()];
array_number.splice(6,1);
const result = Number(array_number.join(''));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let numberWithoutADigit = removeIthDigitFromNumber(789012345, 4);

function removeIthDigitFromNumber(n, i){
    //convert the number n to string as an array of char
    let o = (n + '').split('');
    //remove the item at the index i (0 based) from the array
    o.splice(i, 1);
    //rebuilds the string from the array of char and parse the string to return a number
    let number = parseInt(o.join(''));

    return number;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let x = 789012345
var nums = [];
let i = 0, temp = 0;

while(x > 1){
    nums[i++] = (x % 10);
    x = (x - (x % 10)) / 10;
}

var cnt = 0;

for(--i; i >= 0; i--){
    if (cnt++ == 3) continue;
    temp = temp * 10 + nums[i];
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. You have so many variables here. You should at least explain what the output is. `temp` doesn't exactly look like "answer" to me. Also, you hard-coded in `3`, which makes this a less flexible solution. And as a style thing, there's no reason to use `var`.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let number = 789012345  
let i = 3  // index 3, 4th digit in number

let arr = number.toString().split("").filter((value, index) => index!==i);
// ['7', '8', '9', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']

let new_number = parseInt(arr.join(""))
// 78912345

console.log(new_number)
```

Comment: I would appreciate, let my know reason for downvote ?